# I can't enter recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode

[image]
[image]

I tried every method I found but nothing worked when I try to enter recovery mode, Sony logo appears one second and the device vibrates at the same time any help? My device stuck at Sony logo and it doesn't boot, so I want to hard reset my phone via recovery

Comment: Which model is that phone ? May be this model doesn't have a recovery!

Comment: My device is sony xperia c and I entered into recovery once before ..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138089/discussion-on-question-by-mody3bdo-i-cant-enter-recovery-mode).

Answer (score 2):

Please use  hard reset key method to go into boot loader option . Some devices have two key method some has three . For sony Xperia device it was camera + volume down + power . Please find what is for your device model.

For Xperia C device:
Xperia C device doesn't allow user to go into bootloader using hardware key for this you have to unlock bootloader first .
But you can use flash mode to flash your rom which are as follows : 
1) open adb shell .
2) connect your​ device by pressing volume down key to  laptop​ using usb cable.
3) you can now run scripts on adb shell to install custom roms etc.

Update :
Now when you unlocked your boot loader the official website will guide you to download few drivers and software. I will explain you that with details :
[image]

Now download android sdk which link are mentioned on website . [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

It is not mandatory to download android studio you can also download SDK without android studio IDE.

[image]

SDK : [Official Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) / [filehippo Link](http://filehippo.com/download_android_sdk/)

 Now run sdk manager [image]

 Here you will find all the tools mentioned on website to download . Download and install them :
[image]

 Now go to the downloaded folder of Google USB driver:
Replace the original android_winusb.inf-file with the [downloaded](https://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/fastboot-driver/) file in the usb_driver. ( which you have downloaded in step a.2 )

Make sure you have installed ADB driver for your xperia C . 
[Link](https://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-c-driver/)

Now proceed further . I hope you will not get any error after this .[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138090/discussion-on-answer-by-amit-sharma-i-cant-enter-recovery-mode).